# Probability - Plant Production

Tags: probability, risk

I work for an agricultural company.  We grow plant varieties that yield fruit.  Some varieties do well, others do not.  All plants need the key drivers of success: good soil, water, sun, etc.

So here is the question.  We have what we call blocks, which are defined as a piece of land and a specific variety of plant.  A block is always one specific variety, but the number of plants in the block can vary.  Some blocks produce good plants and others produce poor plants.  Based on probabilities, how can we calculate whether it is better to get a higher number of good plants by more or less blocks?

Should we have less blocks or more blocks?  The goal is to get more plants that are worthy of being used to produce fruit.